# Why does Google Code Prettifier stop working when I use JQuery DatePicker (or vice versa)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, google-code-prettify

If the [Google Code Prettifier](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (or [JQuery Syntax Highlighter](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-syntaxhighlighter)) is being used in the same page as the [JQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), neither will work properly.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they both monkey patch a now method onto the native Date object!

Prettify does this:

```
var clock = Date;
if (!clock['now']) {
  clock = { 'now': function () { return +(new Date); } };
}
```

DatePicker does this:

```
Date.now=function(){return new Date();}
```

So Prettify's returns an int representation of the Date (so that it can add on some ms) while DatePicker returns a Date.

(IMO this kind of thing is outrageous in two such commonly-used libraries.)